# How to Save custom data from admin->system->configuration magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, system-config, system-configuration

I am working in magento 1.9 . I have created a custom tab in **admin -> configuration** . There I created custom fields , I want to save the data from those custom fields on click **"save config"** button.
Here is my code from **system.xml**

```
 <section_two translate="label">
                <label>Carrier</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <carriers>
                        <frontend_model>LtlFreight/adminhtml_system_config_form_carriers</frontend_model>
                        <sort_order>9</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </carriers>
                </fields>
            </section_two>
```

This my code from **.phtml**

```
 <tbody>
    <?php 

    $counter = 1;
    $storeId  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('LtlFreight/section_two/carriers',$storeId);
    $output_data = array();
    $output_data= json_decode($configValue);

    foreach($output_data as $key=>$config_data){

        foreach($config_data as $k => $data){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
               echo  $counter;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
               echo $data->CarrierName;
            echo "</td>";  
            echo "<td>";
               echo '<img src="'.$data->CarrierLogoUrl.'"  height="50" width="70">';
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
               echo '<input type="checkbox" name="" value="'.$data->CarrierSCAC.'"  class="cerasisQuoteServices" >' ;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $counter++;
            }

        }?>
    </tbody>
```

Here I want to save the values of checkboxes on click "**save config**" button . 
Anybody please tell the procedure .

Comment: data on `system > configuration` page is saved automatically on save.

Comment: can you post  your all files here with full code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `config.xml` add code as follows:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
    <observers>
       <myobserver>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>yourextension/observer</class>
           <method>yourmethod</method> 
       </myobserver>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
```

and declare the observer as

```
class Vendor_Extension_observer {
     public function yourmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

         //To get Request parameters in the Observer, use following code
         Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

         //To get post variable
         Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('your-param');
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help , could you please tell me where should i place your code in config.xml? should i place it in event tag or in default tag ?

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the post data of config data (actually i only want to get the selected values from checkboxes in post)

Comment: you need to add code into <events>  into config.xml.

Comment: I update answer with, how we can get params or post value. you can check it.
And if answer help, mark as solution so it will help other in community as well.

Comment: thank you for your help , but i want to get the values of selected checkboxes from custom config data . but Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams(); did show that data . thank you in advance .

Comment: you need to specify same group of that checkbox and also assign name and id attribute to that checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check section name, otherwise, the method will fire not only when you need.

```
    public function yourmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
 $section = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
            if ($section['section'] == 'YOUR_SECTION_NAME') {
    $fieldsData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost(groups)[YOUR_GROUP][fields];
    }
}
```